# How can I add custom margin in grid system and keep it responsive?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

So I am trying to add 4 "cards" (non bootstrap) to my HTML, with space in between them, here is a picture on how it **should** look:
[image: picture]

The issue is that well 1. It is no longer responsive after I changed "col" class to "col-6", here is how it looks right now:
[image: pic1]
And here is how it looks when I make my browser smaller:
[image: pic2]

The margin in between each "card" is
Horizontal - 464px
Vertical - 100px (from image to text)

I haven't really worked with the grid system in bootstrap before, read through the documentation and tried a bunch of different "col" values, but doesn't seem to work.

I also tried to just place the cards on the screen, then adding a div around the "images", saying "img_div:nth-child(1) ..." and the same on 3. But that didn't work either!

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="home-title">XelTool</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="home_card">
        <h2 class="card_title">Bazaar Prices</h2>
        <div class="img_div">
          <img
            class="home_img"
            src="/static/img/bazaar prices.png"
            alt="Bazaar Prices"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="home_card">
        <h2 class="card_title">Bazaar Flipper</h2>
        <div class="img_div">
          <img
            class="home_img"
            src="/static/img/bazaar prices.png"
            alt="Bazaar Flipper"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="home_card">
        <h2 class="card_title">Bazaar High Demand</h2>
        <div class="img_div">
          <img
            class="home_img"
            src="/static/img/bazaar prices.png"
            alt="Bazaar High Demand"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="home_card">
        <h2 class="card_title">Bazaar NPC Re-Sell</h2>
        <div class="img_div">
          <img
            class="home_img"
            src="/static/img/bazaar prices.png"
            alt="Bazaar NPC Re-Sell"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the flex alignment portion of the docs?

Comment: no, I'll take a look! Thanks

Comment: I did try it, but don't seem to understand much what they are saying, I did this: https://pastebin.com/VjVKZ6PE , don't really understand where I am supposed to give the spacing in between every item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is perfect, you just didn't give your image a `css` property of `width 100%`

```html
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <h1 class="home-title">XelTool</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="home_card">
        <h2 class="card_title">Bazaar Prices</h2>
        <div class="img_div">
          <img class="home_img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1590594841715-70fe3b7c51ff?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="Bazaar Prices" width="100%" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="home_card">
        <h2 class="card_title">Bazaar Flipper</h2>
        <div class="img_div">
          <img class="home_img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1590594841715-70fe3b7c51ff?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="Bazaar Flipper" width="100%" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="home_card">
        <h2 class="card_title">Bazaar High Demand</h2>
        <div class="img_div">
          <img class="home_img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1590594841715-70fe3b7c51ff?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="Bazaar High Demand" width="100%" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="home_card">
        <h2 class="card_title">Bazaar NPC Re-Sell</h2>
        <div class="img_div">
          <img class="home_img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1590594841715-70fe3b7c51ff?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="Bazaar NPC Re-Sell" width="100%" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, I got that as well. The issue is that I need more spacing in between each "home_card", 464px horizontally.

Comment: Will it work on responsive design also?, i am not sure about that! `464px` is a fixed value

Comment: oh okay, well it is not needed to have, as far as it is a bit of spacing. The issue with that code though (and on the code I had) ^^ is that whenever you make the tab smaller, make it into "phone size", each card overlap each other. As seen on last picture on this thread.

Comment: is that because the original picture is 1920x1080, and I am saying: `width: 350px; height: 200px;` ? Should I go into photoshop and change the picture to 350x200 there?

Comment: The images i have used for this `code snippet` having a resoultion of  much bigger than yours  almost `7930px` but adding `width='100%'` they will always be fit to the content and as i mentioned earlier no matter what size of images you used but by adding 100% width will make responsive according to `col` class. you can run my code snippet and change the resolution of it so you can have better understanding